# Scale rectangle object from middle – fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a rectangle object on fabricjs canvas. Now, when I try to scale the rectangle it always scales from a fixed corner and only expands to the direction where the mouse is. What I want is, when I scale it should scale from center and expand either side.  I tried setting originX and originY but that didn’t work. Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
 top: 150,
 left: 150,
 width: 100,
 height: 100,
 fill: 'black',
 originX: 'center',
 originY: 'center',
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set [**`centeredScaling`**](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#centeredScaling) property to **`true`** for the rectangle object to make its' scale origin to center ...

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'black',
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    centeredScaling: true
});

canvas.add(rect).renderAll();
```

```css
canvas{border: 1px solid #ccc}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```